# TV series about children ending up in father's computer game

Tags: story-identification, tv, virtual-worlds

So, I only saw a single episode of this during my childhood - 10 or more years ago I had guess -  where there is a group of children whose father programmed a game and they ended up in the game and can't get out. Inside the game they have a base inside a tree house and I believe they were able to communicate through the computer screen with people inside the RL house.

Yeah, I know this might sound quite vague, but it was the very first encounter I had with VR and kept me fascinated for ages and might be one of the reasons I got 'into' VR, so would love finding it back.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[image: Pirate Islands - Poster]

[**Pirate Islands**](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0307803/)

> A freak accident sends three Australian kids into a computer-generated
>   world of pirates and swashbuckling heroes. The kids must help a group
>   of adventurers find a buried treasure and a way back to the real
>   world.

Kate, Sarah and Nicholas are the three siblings. More details, especially about the tree house:

> The pirates arrive and chase the gang off the island, causing Sarah to
>   trip against a tree trunk. This triggers a secret entrance inside the
>   tree, which contains stairways up towards a hidden tree house...

And later on...

> A hidden cabinet inside the tree house stores wet boots, which are
>   found by Kate, who discovers they are power-ups in the game which
>   allows the characters to walk on water...

<sup>*~ Edited from [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pirate_Islands)*</sup>

There's a "computer scanner" device which, at the beginning of the show, got damaged and forced the trio into the game world. When they arrive, the pirates steal it away from them. The kids do eventually retrieve it. It's this scanner which (when properly programmed) can transport them back to the real world.

Comment: I'm more than just a little disturbed by the fact that 2003 now counts as "10 or more years ago."

Comment: I hear you, my friend :-)

Comment: Haha, moments like these are the few rare moments in between where I really do feel young :D . Truth be said I was expecting it to be even older and man does it look bad, but thanks so much!  Let's trigger some old memories this weekend :D