# Sci-fi show where a father, and later his son, are sucked into a computer, and transported into various historic moments

Tags: story-identification, tv

I saw this show one time, I can't remember where. I honestly think it was on PBS, but I could be wrong.

The premise of the show is about a son who had a shaky relationship with his dad. His father built some sort of program which sucked him into the computer, and then the son was also brought in, but it seemed to have transported them into history. The son then has to search for his father through various historic moments, while there seems to be some sort of virus that is trying to stop him from doing so.

It’s not *Tron*. I know it sounds similar, but in the pilot I seem to remember the young adult meeting Cleopatra or some sort of princess or queen. Hopefully someone knows what I’m talking about, lol.

Comment: About when did you see it? What decade or half-decade?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Might this be ***[MythQuest](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0273374/?ref_=kw_li_tt)*** (2001)...?

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MythQuest):

> *MythQuest* is a Canadian television series that **originally aired on PBS** in 2001. Produced by Mind's Eye Entertainment, **it stars Meredith Henderson and Christopher Jacot as Cleo and Alex Bellows, two teens whose father Matt disappears into the Cyber Museum, a computer program that, as they discover, allows them to travel into myths by touching an artifact on the screen.**
>
> They become characters in the myths, and strive to keep the myth to its normal progression; a difficult task when confronted by Gorgos, a trickster god who appears in each myth to try to change it. Alex's initial journey into the Cyber Museum is an accident, but soon they both begin searching for their father within the myths. As the series progresses, they realize that their search is much more important than they first realized, as Gorgos is bent on wiping out entire cultures by corrupting their mythologies.

In the first episode, the son, Alex, is pulled into the Greek myth of Theseus, and meets the Cretan princess, Ariadne. Alex's sister, Cleo, stays in the real world, and watches what Alex is doing on the computer screen. They can also communicate with one another by simply talking.

You can view the scene with Princess Ariadne at the 23:10 mark in the video below.

Comment: Yes! This is the show!!!! Ahhh you’re awesome thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps it could be [Zzaap and the Word Master](https://www.bbc.co.uk/programmes/b00szdm6/episodes/guide)?

From [imdb](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt1426777/?ref_=ttpl_pl_tt)

> The story involves two kids, Josie and Peter, who have a go on an educational computer game in school, but get physically sucked in to the computer because the game's been hijacked by the malign Victor Virus, who wants to be unleashed onto the internet so he can take over the world. The kids then have to work their way through the levels of the game, facing various challenges - sometimes physical but mostly educational - along the way. They are helped from the real world by the school's computer technician, Simon, and Frances, another pupil.

Inspired by this [answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/212317) which has a link to a YouTube video of the show.

Comment: Do they interact with historical moments?

Comment: Doesn't appear so -- honed in on "sucked into the computer" and Victor Virus as possible relations to the OP's question. Missing is apparent historical quests and the strained son/father relationship.